# JavaScript - append() not appending a button, but text

Tags: javascript, appendchild

Example:

```
var buttonHTML = "<button>MyButton</button>";
document.getElementById("myDiv").append(buttonHTML);
```

In this case, the function ends up appending the text into the div.

However, if I do the same with JQ:

```
$("#myDiv").append(buttonHTML);
```

In this case it will actually append the button.
Now, for various reasons, I have to use plain JS (not JQ).

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure how it worked with you and appended the element as text here, because there is no .append function in pure JS

But I agree with what [@Sam Judge said in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41334895/200713),and also want to mention that you can do it using javascript without creating nodes one by one using javascript function [Element.insertAdjacentHTML()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)

> insertAdjacentHTML() parses the specified text as HTML or XML and
>   inserts the resulting nodes into the DOM tree at a specified position.
>   It does not reparse the element it is being used on and thus it does
>   not corrupt the existing elements inside the element. This avoiding
>   the extra step of serialization make it much faster than direct
>   innerHTML manipulation.

And there is another option to do the same using the [.innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) but for sure you will need to save what's already inside to do the append effect.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your var `buttonHTML` is just a string of text, if you append it as a child, it will create a DOM textNode, rather than an elementNode. What you want to do instead is something along the lines of the following :

```
var buttonHTML = document.createElement("button");
var buttonText = document.createTextNode("MyButton");
buttonHTML.appendChild(buttonText);

document.getElementById("myDiv").appendChild(buttonHTML)
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the response. I just actually figured that out moments ago.

Comment: I guess I was just curious as to why JQ treats this differently, but then again it doesn't make much difference. Thanks again for confirming!

Comment: Well, jQuery is just a library you can use, so how it treats the DOM is up to the community who wrote it, rather than any official specification. Usually it's a lot more intuitive than vanilla JS, but using vanilla JS so you can familiarize yourself with the DOM is a good idea, and I recommend it highly !

Answer (score -1):

you can try this code

```js
function myFunction() {
  var myButton= document.createElement("button");
  myButton.style.width = "100px";
  myButton.style.height = "30px";
  myButton.style.background = "grey";
  myButton.style.color = "white";
  myButton.innerHTML = "MyButton";

  document.getElementById("demo1").appendChild(myButton);
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">create another button</button>

<p id="demo1"></p>
```